# How rename nested key in array of object in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Document Structure

```
{
  _id: 5,
  grades: [
     { grade_ : 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
     { mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { mean: 85, std: 3 }
  ]
}
```

As per above document structure in mongodb i want rename key grade_ to grade

```
db.collection.update({"_id":5},{"$rename":{"grades.grade_":"grades.grade"}},{"upsert":false,"multi":true})
```

which gives below error

```
"writeError" : {
        "code" : 28,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (grades of grades.grade_) to traverse the element ({grades: [ { grade_: 80.0, mean: 75.0, std: 8.0 }, { mean: 90.0, std: 5.0 }, { mean: 85.0, std: 3.0 } ]})"
    }
```

I want to rename key grade_ to grade, expected output

```
{
  _id: 5,
  grades: [
     { grade : 80, mean: 75, std: 8 },
     { mean: 90, std: 5 },
     { mean: 85, std: 3 }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per MongoDB documentation: (**`$rename` does not work if these fields are in array elements.**)

> For fields in embedded documents, the $rename operator can rename these fields as well as move the fields in and out of embedded documents. $rename does not work if these fields are in array elements.

So, you need to write your custom logic to update.

```
db.collection.find({
  "grades.grade_": { $exists : 1 }
}).forEach( function( doc ) {
  for( i=0; i < doc.grades.length; i++ ) {
    if(doc.grades[i].grade_ != undefined) {
      doc.grades[i].grade = doc.grades[i].grade_;
      delete doc.grades[i].grade_;
    }
  }
  db.collection.update({ _id : doc._id }, doc);
});
```

Comment: Is the space between grades and grade_ intentional? Line two of your example

Comment: @Jacques Must be some typo, Thank you to point out.
But, it will not affect the end result

Answer (score 4):

`$rename` do not works in an array. So,you can use Aggregate framework's `$addField` to rename fields in an array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      grades: {
        $map: {
          input: "$grades",
          as: "grade",
          in: {
            grade: "$$grade.grade_",
            mean: "$$grade.mean",
            std: "$$grade.std"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "grades": [
      {"grade": 80,"mean": 75,"std": 8},
      {"mean": 90,"std": 5},
      {"mean": 85,"std": 3}
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Clink the link and run it, if you want to test it by yourself.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/8FbX6sBrhA3

Comment: This solution will not work for me, as it will require to add all the possible keys in $map.in object. In my case there can be more than 400 possible keys

Comment: @MilanRegmi I am trying to do similar aggregation and having issues. can you help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873974/mongodb-map-nested-array-in-aggregate-function