# MongoDB: Map nested array in aggregate function

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to update property name by using aggregation. Current document

```
[
  {
    _id: 5,
    payLoad: {
      grades: [
        {
          grade_: 80,
          mean: 75
        },
        {
          grade_: 90,
          mean: 80

        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

expected document renaming `grade_` to `grade`

```
[
      {
        _id: 5,
        payLoad: {
          grades: [
            {
              grade: 80,
              mean: 75
            },
            {
              grade: 90,
              mean: 80

            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

To achieve this I am trying to map the aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      payLoad: {
        grades: {
          $map: {
            input: "$grades",
            as: "grade",
            in: {
              grade: "$$grade.grade_",
              mean: "$$grade.mean"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This is not working. Not sure this mapping is right

```
payLoad: {
            grades: {
```

Also tried mapping like `payLoad.grades`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
{
    $addFields: {
        "payLoad.grades": {
            $map: {
                input: "$payLoad.grades",
                as: "grade",
                in: {
                    grade: "$$grade.grade_",
                    mean: "$$grade.mean"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```