# Mongodb rename key in an array of objects

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to update the name of a key inside an object of an array and annoyed due to the inability to make the queries work. I have tried this [How rename nested key in array of object in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57267848/how-rename-nested-key-in-array-of-object-in-mongodb) but I still get the same error I was getting earlier

Here is the document:

```
[
  {
  "accountCreation": [
      {
        "startDateTime": "",
        "endDateTime": "",
        "isDone": "Yes"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is my query:

```
db.collection.update({}, $rename:{
  "accountCreation.$.isDone":"done",
})
```

All I am trying to do is rename the `isDone` key to `done`. Note that this is just one of the many objects that have this key. I am trying to update all the occurences of the `isDone` key  to `done` inside the `accountCreation`

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
fail to run update: write exception: write errors: [cannot use the part (accountCreation of accountCreation.isDone) to traverse the element
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the answers to the link you provided already stated that `$rename` does not work with array.

Nevertheless, you could probably achieve your expected behaviour by using an aggregate with update. You will need to use `$objectToArray` and `$arrayToObject` to wrangle the objects if you have other fields.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$project": {
      accountCreation: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$accountCreation",
          "as": "ac",
          "in": {
            "$objectToArray": "$$ac"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      accountCreation: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$accountCreation",
          "as": "ac",
          "in": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$$ac",
              "as": "kv",
              "in": {
                "$cond": {
                  "if": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$kv.k",
                      "isDone"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    "k": "done",
                    "v": "$$kv.v"
                  },
                  "else": "$$kv"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      accountCreation: {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$accountCreation",
          "as": "ac",
          "in": {
            "$arrayToObject": "$$ac"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WszaL1Thgpx) for your reference.

Comment: thanks for taking a look, i noticed that `aggregate` is not updating but just giving the edited response as an output. Because when I do a `db.collection.find({))` to verify, it shows the `isDone` key again

Comment: @boomchickawawa sorry my bad. updated the answer to change back to use `update`

Comment: this is wiping out the other fields that present in the document and returning just the `accountCreation` array with the updated name when I do a `db.collection.find({})`

Comment: @boomchickawawa you should have stated that your `accountCreation` object contains other fields at the start. Nevertheless, updated the answer to do it in a more generic way.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two steps(mongoDB 4.2+):

**Step 1: Add the new field "done"**

```
db.collection.update({
   "accountCreation": {
          $exists: true
      }
   },
   [
   {
     "$addFields": {
       accountCreation: {
         "$map": {
           "input": "$accountCreation",
           "as": "ac",
           "in": {
          $mergeObjects: [
          "$$ac",
          {
            "done": "$$ac.isDone"
          }
         ]
        }
      }
     }
   }
 }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

Add the field "Done"="$isDone" in all array elements where isDone is found.

[playground_step_1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/smzWSh9oGBC)

**Step 2: Remove the old field "isDone":**

```
  db.collection.update({
   "accountCreation.isDone": {
   "$exists": true
  }
 },
 {
  "$unset": {
    "accountCreation.$[x].isDone": true
 }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
 {
  "x.isDone": {
    $exists: true
  }
}
],
   multi: true
})
```

Explained:

Define arrayFilter x and remove the old field "isDone" from all array elements where it is found

[playground_step_2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wOkgNHH9AAT)

( Afcourse Step 1 need to be executed first!!! )